# How to check if the request body is empty or request body have empty fields in simple way?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, request, http-post

Hi I have the controller which accepts the POST request.

The request body can be empty or with body with null fields : i.e.  or { }

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService UserService;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/tree", method = POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<ResponseUser> controller(@RequestBody(required=false) UserDataRequest request) {
        return UserService.send(request);
    }
}
```

I have service defined as follows :

1. To check if the body is empty ie null
2. To check if the field is null one by one
3. If the fields are null then do step 1 again

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private ResponseEntity<List<ResponseUser>> responseEntity;

    public List<ResponseUser> send(UserDataRequest data){


        //empty body == null
    if(data == null ) {
           // return list1 of type ResponseUser
        }
    else{

       //Check for the fields are present are not
        Optional<String> id = Optional.ofNullable(data.getid());
        Optional<String> search = Optional.ofNullable(data.getsearch());

        //if id is present 
        if (id.isPresent()) {
            // return list2 of type ResponseUser

        }

        //if search is present 
        else if(search.isPresent()){
        // return list3 of type ResponseUser

            }

        else {
        // return list1 of type ResponseUser
        }
    }
    return responseEntity.getBody();
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to not repeat same thing again? Is there any efficient way?

Answer (score 2):

Add Validation annotation to your Pojo class

```
public class UserDataRequest {
@NotNull
private String id;

@NotNull
private String search;
}
```

update your post method to use this validation

```
 public List<ResponseUser> send(@Valid UserDataRequest data){}
```

Comment: It doesn't satisfy all cases Request can be empty or { }.. Also, id and search can be null as well.

Comment: @Pkumar There are additional javax validations such as NotEmpty, NotBlank that can be used

Answer (score 0):

Answer to @Pkumar

If fields: **search**, **id** are String values:

```
if (data == null || !StringUtils.hasText(data.getsearch())) {
   // return list1 of type ResponseUser
}

if (!StringUtils.hasText(data.getid())) {
   // return list2 of type ResponseUser
}

if (!StringUtils.hasText(data.getsearch())) {
   // return list3 of type ResponseUser
}
```

Answer in general if you want to check request is empty:

```
if (request == null) {
   // your logic here
}
```